# How does the CPU RAM affect the hashrate?

Tags: cpu-mining, hashrate, windows

And does it mean that the bigger the RAM, the higher the hashrate thus boosting your mining speeed?

Comment: do you mean cache? cpu's don't have ram

Answer (score 2):

What you mean is CPU cache, not RAM. In general, the bigger the cache, the better for mining Monero.

You can have as much mining-threads as you like but you need 2 MB cache for one thread. So if your CPU has for example 4 MB L3-Cache, the optimal number of threads is 2. If you have 3 MB, you should use 1 thread.

So all depends on the size of the CPU cache